# Is it possible to redirect https request to http endpoint?

Tags: apache, api, testing, proxy

I need to test an application. It is a microservice which uses other APIs. To test it in isolation I want to use mock servers. The problem is that I can't configure the application under test to send requests to http mock server. It sends request using https protocol and port 443 only.However, there is no https-app running on that port. But it is possible to specify a proxy server. I tried to configure apache to run as an https proxy server. This server uses a self-signed certificate for localhost domain. But redirection does not works for https requests.
However, http requests get redirected succesfully if I run proxy server in http mode.
Here is the configiration for the proxy server:

````
<VirtualHost localhost:8098>
        ProxyRequests Off
        SSLEngine On

        ProxyPass        / http://localhost:3001
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001

        SSLCertificateFile localhost.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile localhost.key
</VirtualHost>```
````

Comment: redirection and proxying are 2 very different things - you seem yo be using the terms inter-changeably.

Comment: @symcbean, I understand. I may be wrong. What I need is that requests are not sent to the original URL, but to the one where my server is run. I'm not sure what is the right way to call this.

Comment: You need to proxy the requests, not redirect them. What do you expect "ProxyRequests Off" in your configuration above does?